# ModX TV parameter doesn't display in snippet

Tags: modx, modx-evolution

I have created a TV parameter representing a DropDownList Menu. But when I call it in a snippet via Modx API It doesn't display at all.

here's the TV I made[image]

a here is how I call it

```
$name=$buf['title'].' ( цвет: '.$modx->documentObject['material'].' )';
```

What am I doing wrong? Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TVs are not part of the documentObject; I'm a bit rusty on Evo but you'll need to use [$modx->getTemplateVar()](http://wiki.modxcms.com/index.php/API%3agetTemplateVar) instead:

```
$material = $modx->getTemplateVar('material', "", $modx->documentIdentifier);
$name = $buf['title'] . ' ( цвет: ' . $material . ' )';
```